# Align heights of daughter blocks of different blocks CSS (flex/grid)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Hi, guys! I have a question. I would like to do the same markup as on [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLxmS.png)(CLICK and LOOK!!!) The problem is: the grey line between the top part and bottom part of the card of the cards on the same level should be aligned. As you see in the picture on the first cards' track grey line is lower because of bigger text on the second picture. And on the second cards' track the grey line is higher because there is no overflowed text. We can use flex and grid.

```
<div class="cat-cards">
        <div class="cat-card">
            <img src="">
            <div class="short-description">
                short
            </div>
            <div class="long-description">
                long
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cat-card"></div>
        <div class="cat-card"></div>
    </div>
```

I imagined that the base should be like this, but you can write any suggestions that use grid and flex

```
.cat-cards
{
    display: flex;
}

.cat-card
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 'image' 'short'
                     'long' 'long';
   }

.cat-card img
{
    grid-area: image;
}

.cat-card .short-description
{
    grid-area: short;
}

.cat-card .long-description
{
    grid-area: long;
}
```

Comment: It'd be much more helpful if you add your CSS in the question.

Comment: From my experience this is not doable with CSS alone, neither flex, grid, float or any other technique. A future addition to the CSS syntax (sub-grid) might change this situation, but that's written in the stars. You will need to use some JS

Comment: Are all the images of the same height ?

Comment: yes, all images have the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have interpreted your request correctly I believe you want all rows to expand equally if the content of one row increases in height.

**EXAMPLE**

```css
.Grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr
}

.cat-card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

.cat-card img {  
  max-width: 200px;
}

.long-description{
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  border-top:1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="Grid">

  <div class="cat-card">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    <div class="short-description">
      Title:1
      <br/>Title:2
      <br/>Title:3
      <br/>Title:4
    </div>
    <div class="long-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas. 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat-card">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    <div class="short-description">
      Title:1
      <br/>Title:2
      <br/>Title:3
      <br/>Title:4
      <br/>Title:5
      <br/>Title:6
      <br/>Title:7
      <br/>Title:8
      <br/>Title:9
      <br/>Title:10
    </div>
    <div class="long-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas. 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat-card">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    <div class="short-description">
      Title:1
      <br/>Title:2
      <br/>Title:3
      <br/>Title:4
    </div>
    <div class="long-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas. 
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cat-card">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350">
    <div class="short-description">
      Title:1
      <br/>Title:2
      <br/>Title:3
      <br/>Title:4
    </div>
    <div class="long-description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae mauris arcu. Donec et lorem ac nulla scelerisque egestas. 
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is really close, but I don't like that heights of top and bottom part of cat-card have the same value. And also the height of top part should vary in different rows. So the overflowed text in top right card don't have impact on the bottom cards heights.

Comment: I think it's better to use
`.cat-card
{
     grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.long-description
{
     padding: 10px
}`
It solved the same height of top and bottom of cards. But the same height of all top block is yet here

Comment: @Дарья Using `grid-template-rows` over `grid-auto-rows` is what I would normally use however I thought you specifically wanted to maintain the maintain heights across rows!

Answer (score 0):

Your parent container should always include the `display:flex;` statement. This will ensure any children will get it applied too.
Using the `inline` flex parameter on your children inside a wrapper with something along the lines of `flex:50%` applied on both should do the trick.

You can find more resources below, and I will also edit the code once I am done working for you.

http://flexboxgrid.com/

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The container should not always include `display:flex` if he wants to use `grid`, Which he should as it's a two dimensional framework in the example.

Comment: You could overwrite it in the wrapper. When making use of flexbox your parent container SHOULD always include it. Even if a child container does not, you can override it using the display: grid OP has mentioned. @DreamTeK